# Object type for block Attribute (Gutenberg)

Tags: block-editor

Is there support for type object for block attributes??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. It will be like this:

```
spacing: {
    type: 'object',
    default: {
        margin: {
            global: { ...DIRECTIONS },
            tablet: { ...DIRECTIONS },
            desktop: { ...DIRECTIONS },
            unit: 'px',
            size: 0,
            sync: false,
            syncTablet: false,
            syncDesktop: false
        },
        padding: {
            global: { ...DIRECTIONS },
            tablet: { ...DIRECTIONS },
            desktop: { ...DIRECTIONS },
            unit: 'px',
            size: 0,
            syncGlobal: false,
            syncTablet: false,
            syncDesktop: false
        }
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is.

Here are all types:
The type field MUST be one of the following:

> **null, boolean, object, array, string, integer, number** *(same as integer)*

Source: [https://developer.wordpress.../block-attributes/](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/)

if you need the default value, recreat a object structure with accossitave arrays. In console it will be parsed as a object,. Note if for some reaso is shown as string somthing is wronf in formating of defalut value.

---

Example usage:

On **PHP** side (*in  register_block_type method*)

```
register_block_type(
    ...
    'attributes' => [
        'mediaDimensions' => [
            'type' => 'object',
            'default' => ['width' => '300px', 'height' => '200px']
        ],
    ...
]);
```

On **JS** (*vanila*) side:

```
const [mediaDimensions, setMediaDimensions] = useState(attributes.mediaDimensions);
```

```
    ...
    value: attributes.mediaDimensions.width,
    onChange: (newWidthNumber) => {
         setMediaDimensions({ ...mediaDimensions, width: newWidthNumber});)
    ...
```